# raise error.DuplicateSlashClient("You can't have duplicate SlashCommand instance

Tags: discord, discord.py, discord-api

Сегодня решил поизучать, что такое эти ваши Slash команды. Пишу код, запускаю, и вижу такую ошибку:

```
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    slash = SlashCommand(bot)
  File "/home/runner/ehsquadbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/client.py", line 96, in __init__
    raise error.DuplicateSlashClient("You can't have duplicate SlashCommand instances!")
discord_slash.error.DuplicateSlashClient: You can't have duplicate SlashCommand instances!
```

Держите код до 1-11 строчки:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from discord.utils import get
import random

from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
slash = SlashCommand(bot)
```

Пишу я на repl.it, скорее всего проблема именно и в этом. Может кто помочь?

Answer (score 0):

Все было легко и просто. Нужно было лишь импортировать `discord-py-slash-command`.

`pip install discord-py-slash-command`